# starting from 10, print odd numbers using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, for-loop, output, setinterval, countdown

How can the loop start writing from 10 to 0.

Currently, the **output** is `1,3,5,7,9` but, **I need** it as `9,7,5,3,1`

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: You initialize `i` with `10`, check that it's greater than or equal to `0` and decrement `i`.

Comment: Start with 10 and move to 0 for ex: `for(var i=10; i>=0; i--)`

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
  if (i % 2 != 0) {
    console.log(i)
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, make a habit to add some context about the code you wrote, because it could be easy for you to got the issue/bug based on your understanding, but try to be in others shoes and think how your explanation could help others to solve the problem.